# Is there a way to have all sound output be converted to 5.1 channel?

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card, speakers, logitech-speakers

So, here is my setup. I am running a Dell XPS 720 desktop with Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 with a Sound Blaster X-Fi Xtreme Gamer PCI Audio Sound Card. Model Number: SB0770

I recently purchased a Logitech Z506 5.1 channel Surround Sound Speaker System. It sounds great with just the subwoofer and the front speakers, but it also has a sound bar and two rear speakers as well that for the the most part, are not being used at all. I use this computer to play games and listen to music, both local music and streaming music from Youtube and Spotify/Pandora etc. Most of those sources as I understand it only utilize 2.0 channels and I want to find a way to get it play over all my speakers. Is there some sort of setting or third party program I can use to make all my sound coming from my computer play through all these speakers?

I also have a separate issue with the sub, but I dont know much about speaker systems. It may be nothing. For anyone who is more knowledgeable than me, the other annoyance I have found is that my subwoofer always seems to be making a a pulsing sound from the speaker. I can feel it pulsing when i touch the cone on the bottom. Its like a tapping sound. If i turn the bass way down, i can barely feel it and barely hear it but it is always there nonetheless. Have tried all kinds of settings from my soundcard.No changes. If i turn the bass down on the subwoofer via the dial it has, the sound diminishes and the pulsing is less strong. I bought it from Bestbuy 2 days ago, so I can return it if anyone thinks it is defective. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Virtual Audio Cable?](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm).

You can select the amount of channels you want to use using the software. Basically, you set that to be your default speaker and you have it set up to output to your actual speakers.
 In regards to the configuration, it seems like you want to use the KS Repeater function.